# iCloud Storage with Cordova based app

Tags: ios, sqlite, cordova, icloud

Please forgive me if this is a stupid question/questions.

I'm developing a Cordova-based iOS application. User's data will be stored in a SQLite db. I saw there are specific locations where I can place my database so that it will automatically be backed up to iCloud.

Does this mean the user can log into a new device and the database will automatically be pushed down by iCloud?

All I want is for iCloud to serve as an online backup location. I.e. this is not supposed to be a thing where the user makes a change on one device and it should pull through to another in real time.

What I want is, on startup my app should check whether or not there is a database with the user's data in iCloud. If there are, it should pull the database down. If it does not exist, my app will create a new database, which should be pushed up to iCloud and backed up periodically.

Is this at all possible? And if so, can someone please show me how to do it? I have ZERO knowledge of coding in Swift, I only know Cordova/JS, so pointing me to the Apple Dev docs won't really help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. You can backup your app data using [`BackupWebStorage`](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/guide/platforms/ios/config.html) preference (by default your app data is backup to iCloud).

From official docs:

> **BackupWebStorage** (string, either `none`, `local`, or the default `cloud`):
>   Set to `cloud` to allow web storage data to backup via `iCloud`. Set to
>   `local` to allow only local backups via `iTunes` sync. Set to `none` prevent
>   web storage backups.

So in your case, this preference will be:

```
<preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="cloud"/>
```

In iOS platform (/platforms/ios/cordova/defaults.xml), default setting for `BackupWebStorage` is `cloud`.

You can control this configuration in your app in `config.xml` file.